# Getting access to SVN from CGI Script in Perl using WAMP?

Tags: perl, svn, cgi

I am trying to perform operation on svn to get the log file using `svn log URL` command through CGI script written in Perl. I am using WAMP server for this. All the statements in my Perl script are getting executed normally but svn commands are not. At the same time, simple commands like `svn --help` etc are giving accurate output. I think, before executing `svn log URL` command and trying to print the output to the HTML page (or redirecting to some other file), connection needs to be established from my CGI script to SVN client. Can somebody help me to establish the connection to SVN from my CGI script? Thanks!

```
print  `svn log -v --stop-on-copy --quiet https://svnmirror.XXXXX/branches/BranchName`;
#print `svn --help`;
$creatDate = substr `svn log --stop-on-copy --quiet $branchName | tail -2 | cut -f3 -d "|"`, 1, 10 ;
print "Start Date Is Creation Date(i.e. $creatDate) \n";
```

[As you can see, the line where i am executing the command "svn log URL "is not printing the log file, but if I uncomment the second line (i.e. svn --help), it is giving output. When I am trying to print the "creatDate" variable also, it is printing nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the command-line client from within Perl, use [Alien::SVN](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Alien-SVN-v1.7.3.1/) and use the SVN libraries directly. Calling external programs from within CGI is a potential security issue and often more trouble than using the proper libraries/modules for the job.

There also appears to be a module [specifically for retrieving logs](http://search.cpan.org/~nikc/SVN-Log-0.03/lib/SVN/Log.pm) if that's all you need, but it looks abandoned.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :) But does using Alien::SVN will resolve my issue? Don't I need to write separate code to get log in access to subversion?

Comment: You will need to write code to connect to the server and retrieve the log. That cannot be avoided. But it's preferable to use a Perl module than to call an external program & parse the output. I've made an edit specifically for log.

Comment: Thanks Alot Alroc :-) Will try it and get back to you soon.

Comment: Hai Alroc. When I am trying to install the module it is givine me this error------Running sh configure --libdir=C:\wamp\bin\perl\perl\site\lib\Alien\SVN --prefix=C:\wamp\bin\perl\perl\site PERL=C:\wamp\
bin\perl\perl\bin\perl.exe
'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
configuring SVN failed at inc/My/SVN/Builder.pm line 114, <STDIN> line 3.

Comment: Something went wrong with the Subversion configuration.
    Please attempt to correct it and re-run Build.PL.
Warning: No success on command[C:\wamp\bin\perl\perl\bin\perl.exe Build.PL ]
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.39)
  MSCHWERN/Alien-SVN-v1.7.3.1.tar.gz
  C:\wamp\bin\perl\perl\bin\perl.exe Build.PL  -- NOT OK
Running Build test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running Build install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Alien::SVN'.

Comment: How are you installing the module? Do you have make & a C compiler installed? Read what those errors are telling you - they are telling you exactly what's missing.

Comment: I installed Strawberry PERL which comes as a package with C compiler and make files (according to some forums). Also I tried installing Cygwin. But the same problem is reported. All other CPAN modules are getting installed successfully but not SVN related modules. I tried to configure my WAMP server to work with Subversion, but on adding the SVN MODULES to the httpd.conf file of apache, my WAMP server is not getting started.